# Can I access activation object of the current scope programmatically somehow?

Tags: javascript, scope, cross-browser

I'm trying to some how understand what happens inside a closure and use the variables and functions created inside of it.

My limitation is that I can add as many lines of code I want to the existing closure, but cannot edit any existing ones.

Can this be done?

```
<script>

var scopeClone = {};
(function(scopeClone){
    //Activation Object {}
    scopeClone.a = "a";
    var b = "b" 
    //Activation Object {b:"b"}

    //my custom code here
    //We want to copy activation object properties to scope obj

})(scope);
//At this stage, we want to get -> scopeClone.b = "b"
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure it can be done:
http://interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-10.html

> 10.1.6 Activation Object
>
> The activation object is purely a specification mechanism. It is impossible for an ECMAScript program to access the activation object. It can access members of the activation object, but not the activation object itself. When the call operation is applied to a Reference value whose base object is an activation object, null is used as the this value of the call.

And from here as well:
https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/2tdwcv/are_there_any_backdoor_ways_to_access_the/

> Note that Activation object is an internal mechanism and is never really accessible by program code.